# Are quasiperiodic critical points described by non-unitary CFTs?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, conformal-field-theory, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

In a continuous phase transition driven by quenched disorder, the conformal field theory (CFT) describing the critical point often seems to be non-unitary. An example would be the Anderson localization transition (though as far as I know the critical point is still not that well understood). As I understand it, the non-unitarity is intimately related to the quenched average over the disorder, which can be performed in e.g. a replica treatment.

There are often analogues of disorder-driven transitions in quasiperiodic systems, e.g. with a quasiperiodic potential incommensurate with the lattice structure. For example, there is a quasiperiodic analogue of the Anderson localization transition. There are some important phenomelogical differences between quenched disorder and quasiperiodicity, but qualitatively it seems like there is some similarity between systems of these types, since quasiperiodicity can "look like" a realization of quenched disorder if one only looks at individual lattice points.

I have some related questions about the CFTs describing the critical points of quasiperiodicity-driven phase transitions. In particular,

1. Is it generally expected that they will still be described by non-unitary CFTs?
2. If so, is there some intuition for why this is the case, given there is no longer a disorder average?